# Bitlocker auto enabled on drive

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-11, bitlocker

The Bitlocker encryption was enabled on my partition device E: on its own post after a System Restore. Thus, I don't know where the key is. I am using a local account with no Windows account signed in.
This is a personal computer; the keys are not saved in the Microsoft account.
Only the E: drive is locked, C: drive is open.

Before BitLocker got turned on mysteriously, I had performed a System Restore.

```
C:\Windows\System32>manage-bde -status E: 

BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.22621 
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
 
Volume E: [Label Unknown] 
[Data Volume] 
    Size:                 Unknown GB 
    BitLocker Version:    2.0 
    Conversion Status:    Unknown 
    Percentage Encrypted: Unknown% 
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128 
    Protection Status:    Unknown 
    Lock Status:          Locked 
    Identification Field: Unknown 
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
```

Could anyone guide me ?

Comment: If the drive is encrypted, and you don’t have the recovery key, there isn’t anything that can be done to recover the files, but go ahead and run, *manage-bde.exe -protectors -get e:* and update your question with the output. My first instinct is that the data on the drive is permanently lost.

Comment: I had a similar case once. In my case Bitlocker "engaged" due to some corruption to the drive. I was tedious work to recover the data but I managed to do it (despide everyone saying that it was unrecoverable). Here's [my question including the solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1713828/data-encrypted-on-ssd-after-attempt-to-clone-a-drive), maybe this will give you a few hints. Good luck.